# How does route -n work in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I can understand the output of `strace route -n`, but does `route` really read any of the files in `/proc` to get the routing table? Also, if the routes and IP addresses are stored under `/proc`, why doesn't `strace` show those files being accessed?

```
root@xxxx:/etc/postfix# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.21.58.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.21.58.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

**Edit, after more research:**

It seems that `route` *does* read a file under `/proc`: specifically, `/proc/net/route`. How, then, did the routing information get there?

Comment: think about it. do you expect the kernel to read those files whenever there's a routing decision? It's in memory.

Comment: so which program/function adds it into memory?

Comment: this doesn't belong on SO, the "how" is programming related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contents of files in the `/proc` directory, or indeed any directory on which the `proc` filesystem is mounted, is generated on the fly. The various filesystem related system calls are directed at the VFS layer in the Linux kernel to the proc code, which obtains the information from in-memory data structures inside the kernel memory space, formats them, masquerades them as the contents of those files.

[Here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob_plain;f=net/ipv4/route.c;hb=HEAD) is the file responsible for printing out the routing information for IPv4 in the kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does use `/proc`, see that part of the `strace route -n` output:

```
open("/proc/net/route", O_RDONLY)       = 3
```

it reads all the information from there. The source of the information is the kernel itself. The kernel offers the routing information via files in the `procfs`.

Files in `/proc` are usually generated and filled (with information) by the kernel itself. Via this interface, the kernel can safely provide internal information to userland. In most cases, that is even human-readable.

Comment: yeah i saw..cool..how did that info get there?

Answer (score 1):

The initial routing table is loaded from config files at boot time. Later you can manually add entries with the `route` command. Also, `routed` or `gated` listens on the network for routing information and dynamically updates the routing table.